# Forecast 3m LIBOR USD. Budget purpose

Tags: yield-curve, libor, forecasting, irs, budgeting

How can I calculate/budget/find a expectation for the 3 month LIBOR for the next 3monts-4 years?

I am calculating a CF scenario on USD 3month Libor + margin. With swaps and fixed rate this is easy, but I also need to compare this to the expected cashflow with a floating 3 month LIBOR.

What input is normally used to budget with 3m LIBOR? I would really appreciate a quick and good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a perfect forecast for interest rates is a bit hard to come by, such a thing would make the inventor quite a tidy sum. Broadly, the task you're seeking to accomplish falls under the banner of yield curve modeling, and there is a very substantial body of research in this area, including several [good books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1403947260).

There are some canonical examples of interest rate models, which mostly leverage the apparently mean reverting behavior of interest rate markets to construct a yield curve. One such model is the Diebold-Li model, an implementation of which is described at [this](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/fininst/examples/fitting-the-diebold-li-model.html) link. This model is a four parameter forecasting tool for various interest rate regimes which takes into account the mean reverting behavior inherent in interest rates (they are generally believed to follow a ornstein uhlenbeck mean reverting stochastic process).

Another alternative is to calculate expectations implied by various maturity bonds. This can be done using various [semi/non parametric smoothing methods](http://people.math.aau.dk/~esben/teaching/13-fs/tanggaardRQFA.pdf). For this, you can use all of the estimators involved in non-linear regression. To my knowledge, no one technique has been proven superior.

Ultimately, this is an estimation problem. It isn't like option pricing where there is a single correct answer given a baseline set of regularity conditions.